# Swift nil values behaviour

Tags: objective-c, swift

Can you send messages to `nil` in `Swift` the same way you can in `Objective-C` without causing a crash?

I tried looking into the documentation and couldn't find anything relating to this.

Comment: Did you try creating a new project specifically for testing this?

Comment: Check out the Optional Chaining chapter in "The Swift Programming Language" book.

Comment: @NSArray No. I don't have OS X Yosemite so I can't run the latest XCode, I am just reading about it on the web and was wondering. That's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly, you have to use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). In swift, an instance can only be `nil` if it is declared as an "optional" type. Normally this looks like this:

```
var optionalString : String?
```

**Notice the `?` after the `String`** That is what makes it possible to be nil

You cannot call a method on that variable unless you first "unwrap" it, unless you use the aforementioned Optional Chaining.

With optional chaining you can call multiple methods deep, that all allow for a nil value to be returned:

```
var optionalResult = optionalString.method1()?.method2()?.method3()
```

`optionalResult` can also be nil. If any of the methods in the chain return nil, methods after it are not called, instead optionalResult immediately gets set to nil.

You cannot deal directly with an optional value until you explicitly handle the case that it is nil. You can do that in one of two ways:

### Force it to unwrap blindly

```
println(optionalString!)
```

This will throw a runtime error if it is nil, so you should be very sure that it is not nil

### Test if it is nil

You can do this by using a simple if statement:

```
if optionalString {
    println(optionalString!)
}
else {
    // it was nil
}
```

or you can assign it to a scoped variable so that you don't have to forcefully unwrap it:

```
if let nonoptionalString = optionalString {
    println(nonoptionalString)
}
else {
   // it was nil
}
```

Comment: Not nil, None.  Swift makes it unreasonably hard to make nil representable.

Comment: @CodaFi Optional.None and nil are the same thing. I also do not agree that it is unreasonably hard, I would say it is reasonably hard

Comment: A bit of hyperbole to lighten the mood ;). And I get the impression from "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" that they may be semantically equivalent, but I doubt definitional equivalence.  Then again, who knows?

Comment: @CodaFi ahah ok. I think that we do know `Optional.None === nil` returns true. Also, everywhere you can use `Optional.None`, you can use `nil`. In fact, in the videos and the book Apple almost always refers to it as `nil`